# Shell Script: Read the first line of properties file separately form the rest of the lines

Tags: linux, shell

I am writing a shell script that reads a properties file & perfroms some operation.

That is it reads from fist line of the prop file.

Now in this script I want to add a switch which if ENABLED will execute the script and will perform the regular operation.

If DISABLED will exit the program noramally.
I want to put this swich in the same prop file. (i.e. Now the first line of the prop file will be either ENABLED or DISABLED)

Currently I'm using:

```
cat init_token.properties | while read line
```

Now before this I want to separately read the value of the switch & then if ENABLED, the while read line should start form the **second line** of the properties file.
In nutshell, I want to segrigate the reading of the Ist line and then the rest.

Format of init_token.properties:

```
ENABLED
abc.dat IP  120.210.60.1
xyz.dat PORT    8200
pqr.dat IP  420.24012.4
```

Script:

```
#!/bin/ksh

dos2unix init_token.properties &

# PATH for DAT files
DAT_FILE_PATH='.'

cat init_token.properties | while read line
do
        #       PARAMETER EXAMPLE - <FILENAME> <ATTRIBUTE> <VALUE>
        #       read FILENAME
        FILENAME=`echo "$line" | awk -F " " '{print $1}'`
        #       read ATTRIBUTE
        ATTRIBUTE=`echo "$line" | awk -F " " '{print $2}'`
        #       read VALUE
        VALUE=`echo "$line" | awk -F " " '{print $3}'`
        #       setting fully qualified filepath name & temporary file
        FULLPATH=$DAT_FILE_PATH"/"$FILENAME
        TEMP_FILE=tempfile
        old='$('$FILENAME'_'$ATTRIBUTE')'
        #       replace $(<FILEANME>_<ATTRIBUTE>) with VALUE if file exists
        if [ -e $FULLPATH ]
        then
                sed 's/'$old'/'$VALUE'/g' $FULLPATH > $TEMP_FILE && mv $TEMP_FILE $FULLPATH
        else
                echo 'File '$FULLPATH' does not exists while replacing token '$old
        fi
done
exit
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something like this, perhaps?

```
    let CNTR=0

    cat init_token.properties | while read line
    do
            let CNTR=CNTR+1

            if [ $X == 1 ]; then
                 //is first line
            else
                 //is not first line
            fi

            #       PARAMETER EXAMPLE - <FILENAME> <ATTRIBUTE> <VALUE>
            #       read FILENAME
            FILENAME=`echo "$line" | awk -F " " '{print $1}'`
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like this at the top of your script:

```
CHECK=$(head -n 1 prop.file)

if [ "$CHECK" == "DISABLED" ]; then
     exit 0
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

First you can split the line with `read`, so you don't need to use `echo | awk`:

```
cat init_token.properties | while read filename attribute value
do
```

Next are the checks for ENABLED/DISABLED/other:

```
    case "$filename" in
    ENABLED) ;;
    DISABLED) exit ;;
    *)
        # It's another line, do processing
        ...
        ;;
    esac
done
```

Another point: don't put `dos2unix ...` in the background. It may run longer than your script does. Just call it without `&`:

```
dos2unix init_token.properties
```